# A memory leak happened when doing ftp request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I find a memory leak when I am testing  my app on ios device, look at the code below:

```
- (void)_startReceive
// Starts a connection to download the current URL.
{
    // Open a CFFTPStream for the URL.
    CFReadStreamRef ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);

    assert(ftpStream != NULL);

    self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) ftpStream;

    self.networkStream.delegate = self;
    [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:RUNLOOPMODEL];

    [self.networkStream open];

    CFRelease(ftpStream);
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
// An NSStream delegate callback that's called when events happen on our 
// network stream.
{
    if (self.networkStream  == nil) {    //EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1,address=......)
        NSLog(@"here");
    }


    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
        } break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            NSInteger       bytesRead;
            uint8_t         buffer[LISTDOCBUFFER];
     ......
｝
```

I use this code to do a ftp request for document information. But only sometimes (one of eight times) the memory leak will happen at the line I note. And On testing on ios simulator, this never happened. I want to know the possible reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be anything but most likely to be invalid memory management. You can analyze your project in your XCode, go to the Project tab and select analyze where the memory leak is actually happening or you can run Profile from the same pathway to detect any particular memory leaks. Check out this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial), it is a really cool topic on how to debug memory related issues.

Answer (score 0):

After type casting ftpStream into NSInputStream you are releasing it (CFRelease(ftpStream)) and again using it `if (self.networkStream  == nil)`.Do not call CFRelease() on ftpStream and release NSInputStream once you are done with it.

Comment: ftpStream is created by "CFReadStreamRef ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (CFURLRef) url);" so after doing "self.networkStream = (NSInputStream *) ftpStream;
" I think it is right to release ftpStream by doing "CFRelease(ftpStream);
"

Comment: You are just assigning it to networkStream but not retaining it.Therefore you should not release ftpStream.if you create a Core Foundation object but then cast it to an NSObject, then you need to release NSObject once done.